# Placeholder/Draft questions

Tags: discussion

There is currently [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012439/the-draft-of-the-question-to-be-continued) that only contains code & no question. The title is "The draft of the question, to be continued" showing that the user intends on adding context to the question. The user has over 8k reputation on Stack Overflow.

The question is: how long should a self-identified incomplete question be left? Should this be flagged & only have a question asked when it is ready to be asked/answered?

Does this user gain any advantage by having a question opened earlier & editing it when ready?

At the time of this post, the question has been asked 1.5 hours ago & not yet edited.

Edit: The post has now been removed, but I believe that the first question is still valid.

Comment: The user had forever to prepare their question. The proper amount of time is none. There is no reason to post a draft on Stack.

Comment: I think only being tagged with "todo" saved it. If it had a language tag it would have been closed and deleted by users in the first few minutes.

Comment: Stack overflow mobile app has this feature :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yeah, I have no idea what happened there. At 8k reputation, the user should know better. I'm chalking it up to a mistake. Maybe they accidentally submitted when they were trying to just use [our stored drafts feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting/66238#66238) (uses HTML 5 local storage, so accessible only on the same computer, and never made public).

> How long should a self-identified incomplete question be left?

Zero seconds.

Same as [how long you should wait before voting to close a question that is unclear or incomplete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close).

We aren't a public scratchpad. Don't go live unless you're ready. As [Patrice commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380938/placeholder-draft-questions#comment675285_380938), you have an infinite amount of time to prepare your question before hitting the "Submit" button.

> Should this be flagged & only have a question asked when it is ready to be asked/answered?

Yes, absolutely.

Someone else already flagged it, about an hour ago. I just got around to processing the flag some 10 minutes ago, when I deleted the question outright. (That's why you can't see it anymore.)

> Does this user gain any advantage by having a question opened earlier & editing it when ready?

I cannot imagine what. Perhaps an earlier "creation" date, but also clear evidence of what happened in the post timeline/revision history. Also, as [ChrisF pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380939), it gives plenty of time for downvotes to roll in. Not to mention the reality of it getting deleted, either by a moderator in response to a flag or by a group of users with deletion privileges.

Fun fact: since this question was deleted by a diamond moderator, the user who posted it is unable to undelete it themselves. Also note that, even if it wasn't deleted by a moderator, you cannot edit self-deleted questions, so the possible abuse vector of posting an incomplete question, deleting it, editing it into shape later, and then undeleting it is actually closed.

A high-reputation user who has a history of high-value contributions is unlikely to trip the automatic question block by having a single question downvoted and deleted, but it certainly doesn't benefit them in any way to do so.

Answer (score 14):

There are no advantages to posting a draft and editing it later, only disadvantages.

If the question is incomplete then it will be down-voted, closed and more than likely deleted quite quickly. Even if they manage to edit the question into shape before it's closed or deleted it's highly likely that its score will never recover from the initial down-votes.

Once the question is deleted it will also contribute to the automatic low-quality question block, and may even cause the block.

As Patrice points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380938/placeholder-draft-questions#comment675285_380938) they've had all the time they need to prepare their question before posting it, we don't need to allow drafts here.

Comment: One more downside is essentially loosing initial 5 minutes of exposure on first page to really get answers...

Comment: @Alexei that's only partially true as the edit would bump the question back to the home page.

Answer (score -3):

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

May be a bit late to this conversation, but this type of feature may be helpful to some people researching a ***potential*** [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) between say the mobile site vs the desktop site.

---

In my case, the following actions were taken to publish a complete post:


**Mobile**:

take screenshot(s) of potential bug(s)

type up the question

check question for grammar/typo(s)

preview -> post review


**Desktop**:

power on, wake, etc.

navigate to SO, logon, etc.

screenshot another set of the potential bug(s) in order to compare the actual vs expected behavior for questions raised recently on SO meta.

edit the post in question to update with additional info and/or file(s) based on review from desktop behavior


A reasonable timeout could be applied to these 'draft' questions before they are auto-deleted by the system (i.e. 2 minutes) so they do not rapidly queue up and waste server storage. I don't have the exact stats on the number of posts to warrant this feature but it could be a handy feature for some.

For example, this exact situation took place which prompted me to raise these
[open questions tagged as bugs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D%20user%3A11472002%20duplicate%3Ano%20answers%3A0)

Comment: There are Markdown editors for every OS out there, so you can draft your questions there. Use an online storage facility to transfer the document from mobile to desktop if you lack the ability to transfer from your mobile to your desktop.

Comment: While there are external tools to expedite these types of posts having it directly on the editor would be far better.

Comment: Maybe if you can come up with a list of other scenarios where the feature might be useful, it might be a better sale. Just the one scenario is a bit weak to implement a whole new feature. This one case is good, just not enough I'd say.

Comment: If it is indeed a Meta post specifically about cross-device behavior then I think you can use the original approach described here (post from mobile, add a notice on top saying that desktop screenshots will follow, then immediately edit the post from desktop). In such a special case the community will probably understand why you do it this way and will not close the question right away. On Main (e.g., cross-compiling with a Makefile on the host and an error message on the target) it might still be closed though because the chance you don't come back to edit is higher than on Meta.

Comment: I don't disagree with the fundamental idea that it might be useful especially for new users to receive feedback without the (implied or peceived penalties of) closing when they explore the site. There are several problems with this proposal, though, beginning with it being posted as an "answer" to a tangentially related old question.